# extract iis saved password

Tags: windows, security, iis, password

In IIS6 settings for a domain, under the Directory Securty » Authentication and access control » Enable anonymous access, there's typically a user name and password supplied specifying the user credentials used for anonymous access.

As that password must be saved somewhere, how would you go about retrieving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I hate answering my own question....

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIIS, strMessage
Set objIIS = GetObject ("IIS://localhost/w3svc")
strMessage = "The metabase reports the anonymous credentials as:" _
& vbcrlf & " AnonymousUserName = " & objIIS.Get("AnonymousUserName") _
& vbcrlf & " AnonymousUserPass = " & objIIS.Get("AnonymousUserPass")
Set objIIS = Nothing
WScript.Echo strMessage
```

[Found Here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine128.htm)

A more generic solution (one which can retrieve the password for *any* domain) would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, don't forget to mark it as accepted! =)

Comment: I'm waiting to see if someone puts up a better answer.

Comment: What do you mean "for any domain"?